# Please help - How do you get Raspberry Pi out of the rebooting screen and onto the desktop?

Tags: boot-issues

I'm using my Raspberry Pi (Model B) and after I used the command `startx` on the LXTerminal it went straight to graphic interface. I tried to reboot back to my old desktop, but now it was asking for a login that it has never asked before after the initial booting.

I used the default login which is `pi:raspberry`. Then I used the `startx` command again in hope of exiting out of it through `ctrl+alt+f1`. It displayed the error: `xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/pi/.Xauthority` and I think I corrected it. Now I'm trying to make my Raspberry Pi perform autologin by accessing sudo nano /etc/inittab and make `1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1` into a comment by putting a pound sign right before it and saving the changes.

Now I have rebooted the pi and it has stayed on a blinking cursor ever since not allowing me to do anything. Any solutions?

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

`sudo raspi-config`

In menu:

`Boot Options -> Enable Boot to Desktop/Scratch`

To add automatic login, in `/etc/inittab` on `tty1` add a line such as:

`1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f root tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1 # RPICFG_TO_DISABLE`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using the command `sudo chown -R pi:pi /home/pi`. This gave access back to the local pi user.